# How to turn off the dotted box in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

When I move my cursor to a parameter, the background's hightlight turns green, and when I edit the parameter, there's a dotted box. I want to know how to turn off this feature.

[image]
[image: dotted box]

Comment: Click anywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my [Plain Rename](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyVlasov.PlainRename) extension to disable the dotted box.